# Tcolorbox automatically indents the text after the equation

Tags: equations, tcolorbox, indentation, paragraphs

I have a problem I do not know how to solve. I am using tcolorbox to create equations which are colorful with a frame. However, after the equation the text that follows is always indented, even though I have no space in between text and equation in the code. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{colorBox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!90,
  colback  = #2!35, 
  coltitle = #2!20!white,
  sharp corners,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  drop lifted shadow,
  title    = {#3},
  #1,
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{colorBox}{red}{Equation}
    \begin{equation}
        a=b
    \end{equation}
\end{colorBox}
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

What I would like that there is no indentation after the colored equation, so it is still the same paragraph.

Comment: `\noindent\lipsum...`?

Comment: wow, so simple. thanks! i was just wondering if there is any general solution in the colorbox definition that I would not need to write \noindent every time?

Comment: or use the option `after` to set the `after` key to an empty value (by default it inserts a \par and so the \@doenpe-test is lost. If you still want some space use e.g. `after=\vspace{1cm}`

Comment: @AndrisErglis  That's why it was only a comment .... But you did say you didn't know how to solve it rather than that you didn't like the solution you had :).

Comment: @cfr it's fine, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the code inserted by the `after` key so that is not longer issues a `\par`, either by setting it to an empty value or to some space:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{colorBox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!90,
  colback  = #2!35, 
  coltitle = #2!20!white,
  sharp corners,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  drop lifted shadow,
  title    = {#3},
  #1,after=\vspace{1cm}
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{colorBox}{red}{Equation}
    \begin{equation}
        a=b
    \end{equation}
\end{colorBox}
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image]